# C# storing cookies with an Exp. Date but it only being stored like a session

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies, session-cookies

I am trying to store a cookie in which i will later user

```
 var cookieOPtions = new CookieOptions {
                Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)
            };
 Response.Cookies.Append("cookieName", "someData", cookieOPtions);
```

as you can see i am setting the exp date of that cookie, but it is still being stored like a session and being deleted as soon as i close my application

[Image of cookie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ij2f.png)

Comment: Are you using an Incognito/Private browser window?

Comment: @Dai no, i am using Mozilla Firefox Dev Edition, just wanted to throw that info in case it helps somehow

Comment: Looking at the screenshot this is running off localhost, are you seeing this behavior only while debugging? Try "debug -> start without debugging" (if using visual studio) and see if you get the same behavior. The browser launched while debugging often doesn't retain things like cookies between launches to make testing things like this from a fresh slate easier.